# Not getting AFL for Visa Contactless Application?

Tags: nfc, payment, emv

I am not getting AFL in the GPO command for Visa contactless Application
GPO Request as Below:
Request :80 A8 00 00 12 83 10 B6 60 40 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 38 39 30 31 00 
Tag 9F 66: Terminal Transaction Qualifiers        : B6 60 40 00
Tag 9F 02: Transaction Amount                     : 00 00 00 01 00 00
Tag 5F 2A: Transaction Currency Code              : 03 56
Tag 9F 37: Unpredictable Number                   : 38 39 30 31

Comment: what is the response you are getting in GPO command. Would be beneficial if you can provide us the command sequence you followed along with the response you got..!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Terminal Transaction Qualifier byte 1 bit 1 is set to zero, meaning "Offline Data Authentication for Online Authorizations not supported". Try setting it to 1: B6 60 40 00 --> B7 60 40 00.

I was having the same issue and this was enough to receive an AFL.

Answer (score 0):

Getting AFL is not mandatory. If you do not get AFL you are not expected to do any READs. You need not do some functions like ODA as you wont have data associated with it. You can proceed with the available data as such.

Answer (score 0):

As per VISA specification (VCPS), AFL is not mandatory.
If it is not returned in GPO the kernel shall **skip** the READ RECORDS and proceeds to Card Read Complete.

Answer (score 0):

I am experimenting now with Visa contactless, Get Processing Options, PDOL, and Read Record commands.
Here is what I found:
Visa Contactless has data accessible via Read Record in either rec 1 or 2, in file 1. You do not need to issue GPO to get this data.

A more complicated case is Visa Contactless inside Google Pay.
Contrary to simple PDOL having 4 elements, this "card" application requests PDOL over 20 elements. I was not able to guess so far the proper values of all of them, to construct proper PDOL and get AFL in GPO APDU Response, and SW=0x90.
The application returns 0 bytes for each Read Record I tried, and so far I cannot find which record file contains application data.

Comment: How do you access file 1? I tried 00 A4 00 00 02 00 01 but it didn't work.